# protractor|selenium not clicked on html element

Tags: selenium, protractor

Help me please with this question.
Did not see the context menu after executing this code.

file: *Grid.js*

```
export default class Grid{
    btnAddClick(){
        browser.wait(async()=>{
                await browser.executeScript('document.querySelector(".Grid--Head--leftButton-plus").click();');
                return EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('.item-invoice_form_add_simple_position a')))
                && EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('.contextmenus')));
            },
            browser.params.timeWaitSelEl,
            'Element "menu point Add position" too long in the DOM.');
    }
}
```

test file: *test.js*

```
it('test', ()=>{
    let grid = new Grid();
    grid.btnAddClick();
    expect(element(by.css('.contextmenus')).isDisplayed())
        .toBeTruthy('contextmenu');
    expect(element(by.css('.contextmenus')).isPresent())
        .toBeTruthy('cont');

});
```

html templates:

`HTML
    <div class="contextmenus"><ul style="z-index: 1000000;">
      <li class=" tab-elem item-invoice_form_add_rate_expense_type"><a cid="c855">Добавить</a></li>
      <li class=" tab-elem item-invoice_form_add_simple_position"><a cid="c857">Добавить позицию</a></li>
    </ul></div>`

`HTML
    <div class="Grid--Head--leftButton theme-color--before Grid--Head--leftButton-plus" style="width: 23px;">
      <div class="Grid--Head--leftButton--helper theme-color"></div>
      <div class="Grid--Head--leftButton--helper theme-color"></div>
      <div class="Grid--Head--leftButton--helper theme-color"></div>
    </div>`

Comment: What error are you getting? I posted some suggestions in Gitter please check if it works please close the GitHub issue which you raised in protractor repo!

Comment: It does not work. I mean it does not resolve the described problem. :(

Comment: can you please post the error/stacktrace which you are facing? That would help in debugging!

Comment: Try the css seector:  .Grid--Head--leftButton-plus in DevTool, then click on the first found element on page manually to see the context menu will displayy or not.  If  display,  try add  some sleep in your code after click, maybe the context menu need some time to load before display.